# What does "in legislation" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, legalese

The following sentence is from a speech by Prince Charles. (minute:second: 11:40-11:48)Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p36MnxSUhJM

**Her majesty's government will establish the UK infrastructure bank in legislation with objectives to support economic growth and the delivery of net zero.**

I know what **"to establish a bank"** means, but I can not figure out **"to establish a bank in legislation"**.

Regards,

Comment: Do you know what "legislation" is?

Comment: James K, yes of course I know what the "legislation" means, but I can't be sure how can a bank be established in legislation. It sounds as if the bank is going to be established on paper, but not in real life, which would be ridiculous. Normally, we say "to establish a bank, a company, an association, etc", we don't need to add "to establish something in legislation", do we?

Comment: That's exaclty right.  It will be established on paper (by law) and that law will give permission for the government to spend money to buy offices, hire staff etc.  Of course we don't need to add "in legislation" since we don't have control of parliament, so we can't create new laws.  The government can.

Comment: Establishment on paper is normal.  I could establish a business on paper by filling out some forms.  The business would be established on paper, even if I never actually start making or selling anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a British locution. But what it means is

> The government will pass legislation to establish an infrastructure bank …

Other ways to say the same thing

> The government, through legislation, will establish …

> The government, by means of legislation, will establish …

Comment: I think it permits them to do much more than legislate.

Comment: It's not that it permits them to legislate.  Parliament doesn't need permission to legislate.  Jeff is saying that the legislation permits them to establish a bank.

Comment: I am not sure whether “permits” is a strong enough word. It would not be in the U.S. The correct word for the effect of such language in the U.S. is “requires.” But I am not sure if the effect is permissive or mandatory in the U.K. Of course, if the language in the legislation itself is “may” rather than “shall,” then even in the U.S., it is permission rather than a mandate.

Answer (score 2):

It means the government will tell parliament to create a new law (legislation) and part of that law will be the establishment, on paper, of this bank.

By establishing a bank "in legislation" it means that it would take further legislation to dissolve the bank. It also permits the government to appropriate public funds to pay for the bank. But after having established the bank in legislation, the government would then have to do the actual "establishment" of finding offices, hiring staff and so forth

Comment: This does extend beyond introducing a single law. The legislative branch of government also holds regular executive offices.

Comment: (i mean offices like companies do, which are considered executive, not like courtrooms with legal people writing letters, but like businesspeople actively converting Saudi Princes!)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. It is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's important to realize 'Her majesty's government' is a special kind of actor. Due to the seperation of (governmental) forces (politics!).

To establish a bank in practice would be to build physical buildings and vaults and etcetera (or to cause it to be done). To do it in legislature, is to establish the laws and procedures, and do so in a way that it becomes legislation.

Legislation is when 'it has been done before, and in that case it was such or so'. Usually, governments must act the same way under the same circumstances; so to produce a legal situation wherin there is clarity by posterity (it happened before and nobody that complained was right, thus proving that it was legal or 'legally possible').

So the addition to the sentence means that 'Her majesty's government', that is to say, the part of the government which is related to the royalty and their power, will cause (to provoke) all the required circumstances (such as examplary financial contracts and transactions), laws (e.g. by the City of London etc) and permissions (by Lords etcetera) to have a legally proven bank.

(with objectives, so many objectives in truth, to support economic growth (of the 'nation' or whatever they call that monsterous conglomerate today I suppose) and to deliver 'net zero' which is some ideal that sounds really ill advised!)

Comment: Her Majesty's government isn't part of the government related to royalty, it is just a long title for "The UK government".  Your definition of legislation is not correct.  Legislation is " is a law or a set of laws that have been passed by Parliament" (not "it has been done before and in that case it was ...") Moreover, there is no requirement for a government to act the same way under the same circumstances (you may be confused by the idea of "precedent").  You are confused on the terminology of "circumstances", "laws", and "permissions".

Comment: This answer is so wrong in so many ways that I am forced to downvote it. For example, a bank of this specialized character will not need vaults. JamesK has specified others.

Comment: The parliament basically just passes a bunch of words. The executive person(s) do real stuff. If they match, it was legislation. This relates innately to precedent, and I insist that whatever was conjectured, they'll require precedent to 'establish' properly.

Comment: I'm not British enough to understand how you guys see 'the majesty's government' as opposed to all the local governments etc. I imagine a lot of the UK considers its governance features not to be derived from or property of the Majesty. I imagine some things are part of Majesty's government and not another 'government organ', whereas other things are part of the Greater United Kingdom and not part of anything Majestic. I could be wrong on that, but specifics like that can suddenly spring up as difficult in exceptional circumstances.